# How to use/define Enums with Flow type checking?

Tags: javascript, enums, flowtype

I'm trying to migrate an existing codebase to use Flow. Since this project started without Flow, I'm using a pretty typical JS pattern for enums and such.

Here are a few definitions I want to

```
export const LOAN_STATUS  = {
  PENDING: 'pending',
  CURRENT: 'current',
  DUE: 'due',
  OVERDUE: 'overdue',
  PENDING_PAYMENT: 'pending_payment',
  CHARGED_OFF: 'charged_off',
  VOIDED: 'voided',
  DISPUTED: 'disputed',
  REFUNDED: 'refunded',
  SETTLED: 'settled',
}

export const ACTIVE_LOAN_STATUS = [
  LOAN_STATUS.OVERDUE,
  LOAN_STATUS.CURRENT,
  LOAN_STATUS.DUE,
  LOAN_STATUS.PENDING_PAYMENT,
]
```

Flow works fine until I import this file and it says I need to add type annotations. This seems odd -- why should I have to annotate objects that are entirely static and easily inferred?

Is there any way that define its type as "static" or "literal"?

So then I go about thinking how I'm going to add annotations to this. My first thought is just `{[key: string]: string}` and `Array<string>`. Flow works, but I'm realizing that these type definitions are totally worthless. So then I try this other approach:

```
type LoanStatusValues =
  'pending' |
  'current' |
  'due' |
  'overdue' |
  'pending_payment' |
  'charged_off' |
  'voided' |
  'disputed' |
  'refunded' |
  'settled'

type LoanStatusKeys =
  'PENDING' |
  'CURRENT' |
  'DUE' |
  'OVERDUE' |
  'PENDING_PAYMENT' |
  'CHARGED_OFF' |
  'VOIDED' |
  'DISPUTED' |
  'REFUNDED' |
  'SETTLED'

type ActiveLoanStatus = 
"current" |
"due" |
"overdue" |
"pending_payment"
```

And I use the type annotations `{[key: LoanStatusKeys]: LoanStatusValues}` and `Array<ActiveLoanStatus>`. But even these annotations loose the fact that this is static!

It just seems so odd that I'm having to write this much duplicate code. And then if I want to convert just to Flow I can't actually use the types in JS. For example I might do this:

```
if (defs.ACTIVE_LOAN_STATUS.indexOf(loan.status) !== -1) {

}
```

Now if I want to use Flow types, I can't do anything like this:

```
type ActiveLoanStatus = 
  "current" |
  "due" |
  "overdue" |
  "pending_payment"

if (loan.status isTypeOf ActiveLoanStatus) {

}
```

So how am I supposed to use these static enums? I must be doing this wrong!

Comment: Relevant Github issue: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/627

Answer (score 19):

To express an enum with flow you can use [$Values](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-values) utility in conjunction with frozen object type:

```
export const LOAN_STATUS = Object.freeze({
  PENDING: 'pending',
  CURRENT: 'current',
  DUE: 'due',
  OVERDUE: 'overdue',
  PENDING_PAYMENT: 'pending_payment',
  CHARGED_OFF: 'charged_off',
  VOIDED: 'voided',
  DISPUTED: 'disputed',
  REFUNDED: 'refunded',
  SETTLED: 'settled',
});

type LoanStatus = $Values<typeof LOAN_STATUS>;

export const ACTIVE_LOAN_STATUS: LoanStatus[] = [
  LOAN_STATUS.OVERDUE,
  LOAN_STATUS.CURRENT,
  LOAN_STATUS.DUE,
  LOAN_STATUS.PENDING_PAYMENT,
]
```

This works starting from [0.60.0](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/Changelog.md#0600) version.

Comment: From the link to the Utility Types doc: “`$Values<T>` represents the union type of all the value types (not the values, but their types!) of the enumerable properties.” So, in your example, the `LoanStatus` type is `string`, not `'pending' | 'current' | ...`.

Comment: @Andrew Patton the trick here is to use frozen object, then value types are resolved as literal types. Give it a try. This part (as many others) is not mentioned in the docs

Comment: That’s really good to know, thanks for the further explanation! Too bad the docs are so incomplete. I did notice that it only works with frozen objects plus string literal values. If any values are variables (even constants), the type becomes `string`. For example: `const PENDING = 'pending'; export const LOAN_STATUS = Object.freeze({ PENDING, DUE: 'due' });`

Comment: An example of the above from the flow REPL: https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBACgUQHIBECSSDiMC8MDkADgKZgAmAlmAOb4DcAUA8QB6EgBOsoksAMgHkAgkgD6AZQAqQyQFVxuGAIBGAK2LAoAOgBmHYsQBexABQBvBjHjJ0WADSWYKWQgBcBMgFdi+B1YEAaggASs5uBCAAbsQcXj5+1qgYmKJwQgCaALLIku5EpJQ0ooQAhgCeALakUL6OAMIAEkLBmAgoogIAYp15wAAWJRzUxGSiIDo6tVYBAmgobXmRIBRkI1NOaOJwspILHhQQhJ5QawnBCJ2yqHv4+jqe5KeO4giSknw3EMRQUAA2TwBfACUjAYUDKJBgfBAJTA4igJSgnggigAJAESr9vBAADzgkjjKHCMRSGTyAB8oNY7C4MB40BgQjqkjQQVEghEEmkcnE7mhsPhiORAG0ALqKYWODkk7nyLSBEJhBLSrlk8RaOqyYLnJCSZXE1U8rRKqUG0lGxBJLCpDLZXUJfA6EAgdYAFgcosYQA

Comment: @Andrew Patton Yes, that's because in flow (not like in typescript) `const`s do not infer literal types, but widen type. To fix this, the type should be specified explicitly (e.g. `const PENDING: 'pending' = 'pending';`)

Comment: Oh yes, thanks a ton guys. Small note it doesn't work on nested object unfortunately. 
I was trying to make something like
```javascript
const TRACK_EVENTS = Object.freeze({
  homepage: {
    header: 'header_passed',
    hero: 'hero_passed',
  }
})

tracker = (eventName: $Values<typeof TRACK_EVENTS>)```

This doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 13):

Here is the most concise way to achieve this:

```
const activeLoanStatuses = {
  current: 'current',
  due: 'due',
  overdue: 'overdue',
  pending_payment: 'pending_payment'
};

const otherLoanStatuses = {
  pending: 'pending',
  charged_off: 'charged_off',
  voided: 'voided',
  disputed: 'disputed',
  refunded: 'refunded',
  settled: 'settled',
};

type ActiveLoanStatus = $Keys<typeof activeLoanStatuses>;
type LoanStatus = $Keys<typeof otherLoanStatuses> | ActiveLoanStatus;

const activeLoanStatusesMap: { [key: LoanStatus]: ?ActiveLoanStatus} = activeLoanStatuses;

if (activeLoanStatusesMap[loan.status]) {

}
```

Comment: hmm. and if the keys arent equal to the values...?

Comment: You'll have to duplicate in this case, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

While incredibly verbose, and non-scalable, this falls into Flow's "[Disjoint Unions](https://flowtype.org/docs/disjoint-unions.html#_)" case and such can be implemented using `===`. As they mention on that page, Case Analysis is done via that operator, as javascript naturally does with `switch-case` statements.

In your case, that equates to:

```
switch(loan.status) {
  'pending':
  'current':
  'due':
  'overdue':
  'pending_payment':
  'charged_off':
  'voided':
  'disputed':
  'refunded':
  'settled':
    // your behavior here
}
```

As I mentioned, this is highly verbose in code which uses your types, but to counter that, it has the benefit of defining your types without creating a boilerplate object- you simply define your literal options and union them together (your second implementation).

*This has the obvious downside of coupling your type definition with your implementations of its consumers, so use with caution.*