# flow type for "one of object properties"

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Flow has [`keys`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-keys), that lets you say somthing like:

```
   const countries = {
    US: "United States",
    IT: "Italy",
    FR: "France"
   };
   type Country = $Keys<typeof countries>;
   const italy: Country = 'IT';
```

but if I want to have one of the `values` of `Country`, I can't find proper way.

I want something like:

```
function getCountryPopulation(country: $Values<typeof countries>){
...
}
getCountryPopulation(countries.US) //fine
getCountryPopulation("United States") //fine
getCountryPopulation("Canada") //fail
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$Values` [landed in `@0.53.1](https://github.com/facebook/flow/commit/ab0789ade95090c2a07ce1dff0e6511226ed73fd).

Usage, [per vkurchatkin](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/961#issuecomment-309829341):

```
const MyEnum = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar'
};

type MyEnumT = $Values<typeof MyEnum>;

('baz': MyEnumT); // No error
```

For more context:
https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/961

Comment: My read of the question is that he's looking for it to fail when the string is not a value in the object. Here it is passing. My understanding is that `MyEnumT` has essentially become type `string`.

Comment: If you freeze the enum object, then the `('baz': MyEnumT);` will give an error, which I guess is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with some duplicate code:

```
type Country =  "United States" | "Italy" | "France";

type Countries = {
  US: Country,
  IT: Country,
  FR: Country
}

const countries: Countries = {
  US: "United States",
  IT: "Italy",
  FR: "France"
};

function getCountryPopulation(country: Country) {
  return;
}

getCountryPopulation(countries.US) //fine
getCountryPopulation("United States") //fine
getCountryPopulation("Canada") //fail
```

Related issue: [How to use/define Enums with Flow type checking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154870/how-to-use-define-enums-with-flow-type-checking)

Comment: well, the whole point was to remove duplication. prefer no types rather than non-DRY code