# How to use string value as a literal type in Flowtype?

Tags: enums, flowtype

Typescript allows me to have a definition like:

```
export enum LineType {
  Adventure,
  Lift
}

export type AdventureLine =
{
  type: LineType.Adventure;
}
```

I can do similar things in Flow:

```
export const LineType = {
  Adventure: "Adventure",
  Lift: "Lift"
}
Object.freeze(LineType);
export type LineTypeEnum = $Enum<typeof LineType>;

export type AdventureLine =
{
  type: LineType.Adventure;
}
```

but this doesn't compile `type: LineType.Adventure;` - Flow says: "Cannot use string as a type". Sure I could write `type: "Adventure";`, but that's not very DRY.

So how do I use string value as a literal type in Flow?

Answer (score 2):

What about [this](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAggEwG4FMxQK4CcUC4YBEiq62KBMAvIcWpjgQNwBQoksAMgJYBmU+BbnwrVBvKE2bMUADwAOILLDbQY3MCgAqATzkoqMAN4x4yOmQA0JobAC+LAPIAjAFYpgUAHQ8cKAF4oABTqWrooAJQssgpKMFBhalwaOnoAomAYALYGACTpWQA88XogPInJYQB8LNLyirDF+rSkOCFUzIbMJo34jaXloXqezfQoLLZSgcY9NGYt5DC2+CNkIZGT02ECMhRLpiSja4xAA)?

```
const Adventure: "Adventure" = "Adventure";
const Lift: "Lift" = "Lift";

export const LineType = {  Adventure,  Lift };
Object.freeze(LineType);
export type LineTypeEnum = $Enum<typeof LineType>;

export type AdventureLine =
{
  type: typeof LineType.Adventure;
}

({ type: "Adventure" }: AdventureLine); // works

({ type: "x" }: AdventureLine); // gives erros
```

Comment: Nice! It's a bit repetitive, but only in the definition. It seems to do the job. I wish there was something simpler... (like in TS :))

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you?

```
type LineType = { Adventure: "Adventure", Lift: "Lift" };
type AdventureLine = { type: $PropertyType<LineType, 'Adventure'> };

({ type: "Adventure" }: AdventureLine); // no error
({ type: "Lift" }: AdventureLine); // error
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAMglgOwgFXNAvFA3lAggEwDcIFgBXAJwgC4oAiA40yiOgGljgDNha74edKAF8A3AChQkPERLkq8JFEw4pNKABIAChQD2kCqFSQAPIpRoOAckZyWVgHwiJ4gBSq0fW8ypDhtb3kIcwBKUSgAegioBF0oCAo9CjcPSD4BYD8A2R9gxAgwyOiEpKA)

Comment: No, not really. Because you changed LineType to a type from an object. Thus it can not be used the way enums are used: const geometryType = LineType.Adventure;

Comment: Then I'm not sure of a way to do it. Flow doesn't seem to have a parallel to `enum` since JS doesn't have that concept built into the language. Would be cool if `typeof` could be controlled for what level of detail the returned type is (so, for example, `typeof LineType.Adventure` from your example would be `"Adventure"` instead of `string`. Also, take a look at [this proposal](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7837) for adding enums to Flow.

Comment: At the moment I just did "type: LineType & 'Adventure'". This statement on its own doesn't have a proper compile-time safety, i.e. you can give wrong string like "ABC". Although in that case, it won't allow you to create the object at all, so I kinda guess it's better than nothing...

Answer (score 0):

(I know this is an old question but its showing up in search results so I wanted to properly answer how to do it with modern Flow.)

I think the way to accomplish what you want is using the `$Keys<T>` utility operator.

https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-keys

```
// @flow
const LineTypes = {
  Adventure: "Adventure",
  Lift: "Lift",
}

type LineType = $Keys<typeof LineTypes>

const geometryType = LineTypes.Adventure
const AdventureLine: LineType = 'Adventure'

// $ExpectError
const wontWork: LineType = 'Foo'
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBjWA7AzgF1AGQJZoCmAKgJ4AORGoAvKAN6KigCCAJgG5FpYCuAJyIAuUACIO3XoKJiANMzz5IWUWIIr5iAL6JEWSkSXFyVOqAAkAaSJkMAHgNVYkY6UMYAfHtSYcAcyJYAFsiLAEyUyN6AhMPADpJHn4hFHRsNi5kmViRNyjzAHIk6SFCvRBLAFEADypkLCqBAVgBNL9QeHQsAHVWgGtRXIL6QoAxWFhCoA)

Also just to comment on the reason Flow doesn't have an exact equivalent to Typescript's Enum is because Flow is very careful to just be a type system whereas Typescript is a language so it can extend regular Javascript with things like Enum.  So the root reason is: Javascript doesn't have an Enum so Flow doesn't have an Enum.  Once Javascript itself has Enum, Flow will also support it.

Comment: No, this doesn't solve my problem. I have to admit that my question is convoluted - I had to read it myself a few times before I understood what I was after :) Anyway, the issue is that I can not use `LineType.Adventure` as a type (not as a value!). Just try defining a type like this: `export type AdventureLine =
{
  type: LineType.Adventure;
}`

Comment: The `$PropertyType<T, string>` utility operator that @user11307804 used can also be used in this case, although it is quite verbose:  [Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBjWA7AzgF1AGQJZoCmAKgJ4AORGoAvKAN6KigCCAJgG5FpYCuAJyIAuUACIO3XoKJiANMzz5IWUWIIr5iAL6JEWSkSXFyVOqAAkAaSJkMAHgNVYkY6UMYAfHtSYcAcyJYAFsiLAEyUyN6AhMPADpJHn4hFHRsNi5kmViiVgxWADUAQwF8YoAjaBE3KPMAciTpIXq9JyMmlKJc-NY6+gZQRXbRCwAFAVgqAQMox0MXWo85UEas5qJ6zwVdRBBLAFEADypkLAOBSYE0v1B4dCwAdVgBAGtRXP7VgDFYWHqgA)

Comment: so what's the difference between `$PropertyType<typeof LineTypes, 'Adventure'>` and `typeof LineType.Adventure`? Also this code compiles fine `const a: AdventureLineAsAType = { type: "moo" }` in your case when it shouldn't, because result type is `string`. See this answer how to solve it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56717886/217022

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I didn't really understand what you were after at first.  Tried some more attempts (which I'll post as a separate comment due to character limit).  Unfortunately while `$Values<typeof LineTypes>` correctly refines the type of Frozen objects to the string literals, `$PropertyType<typeof LineTypes, 'Adventure'>` still expands it to string.  So ultimately I think Alex Savin's answer is really the best way.

Comment: More attempts with Frozen object and `$Values<>`: [Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBjWA7AzgF1AGQJZoCmAKgJ4AORGoAvKAPIBGAVkclgHSQBORRALyIAKAN6JQoAIIATAG5E0WAK58AXKABEshUtVFNAGgl58kLBs0FzRxAF8AlIkRZKRU8XJU6oACQA1AENoZWoAHlcqWEgPUjcMAD5nVEwcHUUVPikMKS8iGSCefECmaCINAk83HwBydL0+GsQQPwBRAA8qDlaeHlgeFHRsUHh0LAB1foBrCsI473oagDFYWCaXavrM+fd6cUkWgFU0SH6VNECsImgyUCwAC3waIk7AtBkaLFhQbCK0AHNDCN7kQ+IEaAFgqEaP8iFgaPgcKheuwsCYQJFyn4AAp9Kg8Vx5CJuaKxPIYIF1eQZfQ1JKSTEaKm6bZNOzOFq+DpdLA9PoDFLDQIaLb6PI+UR3NyWAC2q00oHZQA)

Comment: you don't need frozen or $Values to define type like that, I mean if you repeat yourself by saying `type: "Adventure"`

Comment: I also didn't know that `$Values` gets the correct type on frozen objects. Thanks for that hint!

Comment: Yes, I left those in there so you could see the issue with $PropertyType if you wanted.  As you say, don't need it if you are using explicit 'Adventure' anyways.  If a more traditional Enum-style use is of interest, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49105296/219238) shows off a clean way with `freeze` and `$Values<>`.